# REST API Spring 3.2.0 successfully deployed on azure but 404 error on endpoint

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, github-actions, cicd

I'm trying to build a cicd pipeline and have made a spring (3.2.0) project (Java 17, gradle) on a simple rest api. At the moment, my pipeline is being built, tested and deployed on azure. All stages are successful, but when I'm on azure and try to reach my endpoint which is "{mywebsite}.azurewebsites.net**/api/students** it shows me a 404 error.
To be more precise, my jar file is "server.jar" and is located in the "build/libs/server.jar" folder.

When I run my project locally, it works perfectly, but when it's on azure, it doesn't, as I get the 404 error. I've tried to resolve my error by modifying :
ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION : didn't work
modify my .yml if it was my jar file after all: didn't work

Also, I went to .scm but when I go to files, I only get files of the type : ASP.NET or DeploymentLogStream. I figured out that these were just environment files and had nothing to do with my project.
Now I don't know what to do because all the topics show the things I did previously. Did anybody had this issue ?

Just in case here is my deploy.yml file:

```
name: Build and deploy JAR app to Azure Web App 


on:
  push:
    branches:
      - dev
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Java version
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: '17'

      - name: Build with Gradle
        run: ./gradlew build

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: build
          path: build/libs/server.jar 

  deploy:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      needs: build
      environment:
        name: 'Production'
        url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
  
      steps:
          - name: Download artifact from build job
            uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
            with:
              name: build
              path: build/libs/
          - name: show files
            run: ls -la
    
          - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
            id: deploy-to-webapp
            uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
            with:
              app-name: 'DevOpsProjectEfrei'
              slot-name: 'Production'
              publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_1BD6BC13408746048A3DDF66BE34382E }}
              package: 'build/libs/server.jar'
```

I've tried to resolve my error by modifying :
ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION : didn't work
modify my .yml if it was my jar file after all: didn't work

Comment: Please share your GitHub repository link if possible.

Comment: Here is the repository : https://github.com/natdoly/Projet_DevOps

Comment: Is your runtime stack set correctly on your app service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have deployed your [spring boot project](https://github.com/natdoly/Projet_DevOps) to **Linux Azure App Service** with **JAVA 17 as Runtime Stack** using ***GitHub actions***:

**My GitHub workflow:**

```
name: Build and deploy JAR app to Azure Web App - springbootproject

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Java version
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: '17'

      - name: Build with Gradle
        run: gradle build

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: build
          path: build/libs/server.jar 

  deploy:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      needs: build
      environment:
        name: 'Production'
        url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
  
      steps:
          - name: Download artifact from build job
            uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
            with:
              name: build
              path: build/libs/
          - name: show files
            run: ls -la
    
          - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
            id: deploy-to-webapp
            uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
            with:
                app-name: 'springbootproject'
                slot-name: 'Production'
                package: '*.jar'
                publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_ECA77XXXXXXXXXXXXX38CF0 }}
```

**Deployment Status in GitHub:**

[image]

**KUDU site of Web App(site/wwwroot):**

- Can see the Jar file of the project:

[image]

- Able to run the application with endpoint `https://<webapp>.azurewebsites.net/api/students`:

[image]

Comment: Wooow ok... I tried to find the difference between my file and yours. I noticed that the lines: package publish-profile were reversed and after making this change, it worked. My question is why does it work after reversing the two lines?

Comment: AFAIK, this is because we are configuring workflow to use the Jar file as package, then publish it to Azure.